# Create 2 pair unique id data rows

Tags: sql-server, mssql-jdbc, sqlclient

I want create 2 data rows with 1 same findable unique id to each one by 1 query

2 difference is ***side*** column {**1** buyer} {**0** seller } and  ***userId*** column {userID's}

```
id userId  side   price   qty   pairId
 1 6       0      60      10    1
 2 9       1      60      10    1
```

trying to visualize result table:

In SQL Server I tried `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`

```
insert into [dbo].[deals] (side, price, qty,pairId) 
values (1, 60, 10 ,SCOPE_IDENTITY()),
       (0, 60, 10 ,SCOPE_IDENTITY()),
```

create table command:

```
CREATE TABLE [demonstration].[dbo].[Deals](
   [id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
   [userId] [int] NULL,
   [side] [smallint] NULL,
   [qty] [decimal](18, 4) NULL,
   [price] [decimal](18, 4) NULL,
   [pairId] [bigint] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? Cannot be both.

Comment: then please remove the mysql tag

Comment: please show your table schema

Comment: why are you using `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` instead of just value `1` ?  Please explain what are you trying to achieve

Comment: please show the create table command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an IDENTITY column to deals table(or alter one column to identity) then use your query:

```
insert into [dbo].[deals] (side, price, qty,pairId) 
values (1, 60, 10 ,IDENT_CURRENT('deals')+1),
       (0, 60, 10 ,IDENT_CURRENT('deals')+1)
```

added +1

Comment: pairId get's last inserted id number is it okey to add +1